# running wp8 simulator on vmware player does not supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I run wp8 simulator on vmware player, but it always reports generic error.
So I run core info and get info

the system does not supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization

Just wonder if this is because of vmware.

Comment: If it does end up being VmWare you can always use HyperV on Windows 8 (it's built into Windows 8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it is the VMware Player giving you the issue. I have some what of a simular setup -  (Windows 7 64 running Windows 8 Professional 64 under VNware Player). I did not have the Windows Phone 8 SDK downloaded, so I downloaded it and tried to create a project and run it under the emulator and I got the same Generic Error. What is probably happening is that you are running a VM inside of a VM which has isolated you from using the Intel processer extensions since you are using an emulated processor.

If I were you I would use the [Securable utility from GRC](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm) to determine wether or not your processor supports 64 bit and hardware extensions. If it does I would then configure your system to dual boot, Xp and Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

> Windows Phone 8 app development is supported only on 64-bit Windows 8
>   Pro or higher. You can't develop Windows Phone 8 apps on Windows 7, on
>   Windows Server 2008, or on Windows Server 2012.

Here You have a system requirments for WP8 Emulator:

[System requirments for Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)